# replacing a duplex outlet

Tags: electrical

The old outlet I wish to replace has a red wire pushed into the push connector and another red wire hooked around a brass terminal. The same is true for the two black wires. My question is should I pigtail the red wires and then just have one red wire attached to a brass terminal and likewise with the two black wires?

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Answer (score 1):

Pigtailing them (from a wirenut connecting the two wires and the pigtail) is a perfectly good approach, yes.

Check the old outlet to see if (likely) the tab connecting the two brass terminals is broken/removed. If it is, do the same on the new outlet before installing it.